# Add image to a form authentication in glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, html, forms, authentication, glassfish

I am trying to add an image to my authentication form but the security credentials keep it from showing, even though the image is not part of the restricted urls.

Am I doing something wrong with the security descriptors that block all my pages?

Here is my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>activedir</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>activedir</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/activedir/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>security</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And here is my glassfish-web.xml

```
<security-role-mapping>
   <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
   <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
<security-role-mapping>
   <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
   <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
 <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
 <class-loader delegate="true"/>
   <jsp-config>
   <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
    <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
 </jsp-config>
```

My folder tree is as follows:

- activedir

  - index.jsp
  - result.jsp
- login

  - login.html
  - error.html
  - logo.png
  - style.css

Now when I authenticate, it does not return to the web page I requested, instead it will redirect to the image.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try allowing the login directory to be read by anyone

```
<security-constraint>     
   <display-name>login</display-name>     
   <web-resource-collection>         
       <web-resource-name>login</web-resource-name>         
          <description/>         
          <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>     
   </web-resource-collection>     
   <auth-constraint>         
       <description/>         
       <role-name>*</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>     
   <user-data-constraint>         
       <description/>         
       <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>     
   </user-data-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. Still the same problem. Is there another way to define everyone including people not in the roles I specified?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show an image in my form-based login-page on Glassfish 4 by defining the full path to the image-URL:

```
<img src="/login/img/html5.png" /> <-- no Image
<img src="https://localhost:8181/App/login/img/html5.png"/> <-- Image!
```

Don't add a security-constraint in your web.xml to the login directory as suggested by rorrohprog (other Answer to this question). No constrain-settings to a folder allows everyone to read from it.